# Should post notice of unclear questions refers to some resources?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, close-reasons, post-notices

<sub>Note: This question may apply best to science sites.</sub>

The current post notice on unclear questions currently says:

> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Presumingly, anyone who is familiar with how Stack Exchange works already try their best to read every relevant Wikipedia pages and suggested questions when drafting the question, clarify their specific problem and highlight exactly what they need. No matter how many new edits are made, the experts still cannot understand the question to provide any insight. The questions should be closed, no doubt on that, but the askers are really hit an invisible wall. If only there are some bug errors showing *feedbacks* for what they've tried.

I think it's because they are lacking a foundation of knowledge, **but they don't know that**. And one cannot read a couple websites to be able to have a foundation, it really takes time to learn. They do see something behind that wall, so they don't think that they are completely blind. **If they know that they are blind, they will grab an introductory book to start learning seriously.** What we need to do is not telling them how to ask, but to tell them where they should start. I think adding a line like this in the post notice will save everyone's time:

> It's also likely that you are lacking basic knowledge on that topic in specific or [math/physics/etc] in general. Try reading a book to gain some insights first.

Books are preferred because they contains **well-developed insights**, cutting out unnecessary details that Wikipedia pages usually have. Internet is not a place for long-term guidance I think.

**Example question**: [What topic focus on how e^x
can transform a functions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26952/157643) in Mathematics.

Comment: `Presumingly, anyone who is familiar with how Stack Exchange works already try their best to read every relevant Wikipedia pages and suggested questions when drafting the question, clarify their specific problem and highlight exactly what they need.` As nice as it would be to presume this, it is *very* frequently not actually a valid assumption, particularly for a question that has been closed.

Comment: Based on no research whatsoever I think we need less text, with a stronger message, preferable fitting in 140 characters.

Comment: @Servy ok, no presuming, but I'm talking on who really do that

Comment: @Ooker So you're proposing this change knowing that it applies to a rather small minority of the people reading it?

Comment: @Servy what do you mean by "reading this"? This post or the post notice? As for minority, homosexual is minority, do we neglect them for the sake of simplicity?

Comment: @Ooker I referred to the reading of your proposed message.  Your analogy makes zero sense.  You're proposing providing guidance to people in which you know that your guidance is going to be wrong *the vast majority* of the time.  That means you're going to be confusing the vast majority of the people reading the close message.  That's harmful.  If you want to help out a particular portion of the user base with a very *specific* problem, that's fine, but don't do it at the expense of *many more* people.

Comment: @Servy I agree that we shouldn't do it at the expense of many more people. But why is this going to be wrong for the majority? The proposing only adds to the current text, not replacing it. If someone sees it fits, then it helps. If not, it's doesn't harm. Why is making the close notice more complete harmful?

Comment: @Ooker The *vast* majority of unclear questions aren't unclear because the question author lacks so much fundamental knowledge of the topic that they need to read a book instead of asking an SO question.  Unclear questions are merely those where the person failed to adequately explain themselves in a way that they could be understood.  Providing completely inapplicable advice *is* harmful, and insinuating that someone is severely lacking in knowledge *when they aren't* is *absolutely* harmful towards a productive discourse in having them improve their question.

Comment: @Servy I see. So it seems that your point is towards those who simply fail to explain themselves clearly, while my point is to those who lacks fundamental knowledge. I agree that the current unclear close reason is made for group 1, and I think you can make it an answer if you wish. Also, since "absolutely" is a very extreme word, can you elaborate more on the harm that will make on group 1? Why can reading that be absolutely harmful toward a productive discourse in having them improve their questions? If they aren't lacking knowledge, they can ignore it, can't they?

Comment: What is a "post notice"?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I didn't check the accurate term, but it's the notice that the community wants to announce about the quality of the post.

Comment: @Ooker So let's say that I closed your meta question because you lack a fundamental understanding of how SO works, and suggest that you go read a book on how the site operates instead of asking your question, because I'm not sure what exactly your proposed change is actually asking and I want to to clarify it in more detail.  If I were to do that would you be more or less likely to try to improve your meta question?

Comment: @PeterMortensen In this particular context, the close reason, although the term "post notice" in general could be sensibly used to refer to any type of banner under a post, including lock reasons, protected banners, etc., but the question appears to only be concerned with close reasons.

Comment: @Servy if that's because I'm lacking a fundamental understanding (group 2), then I of course want to read it. Note that using an analogy on SO doesn't fully convey the importance of reading a whole book; it's unlikely that an internet problem is so abstruse so that no matter how much googling you done you can't even know where exactly your problem is. Will I improve the question? It's likely that I'll leave that until I really know what I need to know.

Comment: @Ooker So do you feel that you lack a fundamental understanding of SO, and that you need to read a book on the subject in order to ask the question that you're asking, or not?

Comment: @Servy no I don't feel that I lack a fundamental understanding of the site. But what do you mean?

Comment: @Ooker Do you feel that being informed that you have a lack of fundamental understanding in the relevant concepts is helpful in you making your question clearer?  Are you not bothered by an accusation that you don't even understand the basics of the topic at hand (when you clearly believe that's not the case)?  Are you more or less likely to take the after being incorrectly accused of not even understanding the basics of the concept?

Comment: @Servy yeah I think that I do feel unhelpful if I'm clearly believe that I understand the basics, yet are told to read a book. But my proposal is just giving another solution to consider ("also, it's likely that"; I'm sorry if this give you the imprison of accusation, I'm not a native English speaker). But that's it. My all intention is just to appreciate a portion of users and don't force anything on them.

Comment: @Ooker But that's just it, it's *not* likely that they don't understand the basics.  It's extremely unlikely that that *isn't* the problem.  Asserting that it's very likely the case is wrong, and means you're giving bad and insulting advice in an overwhelming majority of cases, which will do more *harm* than good.

Comment: @Servy ok, although I think we need more hard data here, I accept your explanations. Any reason that you don't want to make it an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to know everything - you need to ask a question that gives sufficient information for someone else to answer.

Lemme take a recent [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1247746/how-do-i-encrypt-entire-kali-install-with-luke-nuke) I closed on SU.

OP has somewhat of an idea what he's doing - using something called "luke nuke" to encrypt a drive. I have no idea what luke nuke is, and I googled for it.

The question body says:

> I'd like to nuke the entire bootable USB stick main persistent install partition, meaning the os would be nuked

Which... doesn't seem coherent with it.

OP reading Wikipedia wouldn't help here - OP providing relevant links to the tools he's referring to would.

Good questions don't actually need in-depth knowledge of a subject - they need to provide enough information to someone else to be solvable.

Comment: My understanding of this meta question is that it's referring to questions with [this type of problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261859/1159478), where the author of the question lacks so much information *necessary to understand the answer* that answering the question to the point that it could be understood is not possible in the scope of an SO answer.

Comment: @Servy not really. My question is about OP cannot explain their needs coherently because they lack necessary knowledge, not about unable to comprehend the answers. I think your example question is more about "off-topic" close reason.